# core-image-minimal has bluetooth

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am trying to build core-image-minimal receipe for iMx7 (Yocto project), the image gets successfully built but it has bluetooth, caam and lot of other stuff. How can I remove these from including in the minimal-image?

core-image-minimal should only have things required for just booting nothing else, somehow other packages are getting added. I didnt add anything in my local.config file.

MACHINE = "imx7dsabresd"

Answer (score 4):

bluetooth and wifi are enabled here:
[imx7dsabresd.conf](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/blob/776afcc34fe430e5818dec533f04cdb2828a5e3d/conf/machine/imx7dsabresd.conf#L12)

You can add the following to your local.conf to remove bluetooth:

```
MACHINE_FEATURES_remove = "bluetooth"
```

CAAM is enabled in the kernel config here:
[defconfig](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/blob/776afcc34fe430e5818dec533f04cdb2828a5e3d/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-fslc-imx/defconfig#L429)

To change the kernel configuration you can either provide a new defconfig or use a configuration fragment. The following steps describe how to create a config fragment.

Run the following command and deselect the bluetooth related config options:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

Run the following command to generate fragment.cfg in ${WORKDIR}

```
bitbake -c diffconfig virtual/kernel
```

At this point if you do not have your own layer, create one by following this guide:
[Creating Your Own Layer](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-your-own-layer)

Create the directory for the .bbappend and the configuration fragment:

```
mkdir -p ${PATH_TO_YOUR_LAYER}/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-fslc-imx/linux-fslc-imx/
```

Move fragment.cfg from ${WORKDIR} to ${PATH_TO_YOUR_LAYER}/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-fslc-imx/linux-fslc-imx/

Create a ${PATH_TO_YOUR_LAYER}/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-fslc-imx_%.bbappend (assuming linux-fslc-imx is the correct kernel recipe for this board) and place the following in it:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"
```

Additionally, you may find the [Creating Configuration Fragments](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-config-fragments) section of the manual helpful.

For more information about bbappends see:
[mega-manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-bbappend-files)

Comment: I tried removing bluetooth using MACHINE_FEATURES_remove, it did not work. I even tried commenting out the MACHINE_FEATURES += " pci wifi bluetooth" from imx7dsabresd.conf file but no luck.. bluetooth still shows up (I tried by deleting the folders inside the build folder except conf  and downloads folders)

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by bluetooth showing.  Removing bluetooth from MACHINE_FEATURES should remove userspace aspects of bluetooth but won't remove it from kernel configurations like the one in linux-fslc-imx. If you want it removed from the kernel you need to make an append to linux-fslc-imx to remove it from the kernel config.

Comment: by bluetooth showing I mean it is getting included in kernel and it shows up in the boot messages.. I want to remove it from the Kernel.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using append file, can you please point to some examples of append files?

Comment: I updated the answer to include instructions for creating a .bbappend that applies a kernel configuration fragment. Let me know if that works. This assumes you have a custom layer where you can place this .bbappend.

Comment: what if I do not have a custom layer? I could not find fragment.cfg in my ${WORKDIR} after sucessful execution of the commands. Thank you very much

Comment: Do you see a message like this? "Config fragment has been dumped into:
 /home/georgem/devel/oe-upstream/build/tmp-glibc/work/qemux86_64-oe-linux/linux-yocto/4.12.14+gitAUTOINC+cebe198870_9cc6b0ae1a-r0/fragment.cfg" if not, which bitbake version are you using? 'bitbake --version'

Comment: I did not get that message. Bitbake version - 1.37.0

Comment: In meta-freescale linux-fslc, kernel config fragments are broken: https://community.nxp.com/thread/376369. This is because linux-fslc does not use linux-yocto.inc (tsk tsk). The hack to fix config fragments in your .bbappend: do_configure_append() { 
    cat ${WORKDIR}/*.cfg >> ${B}/.config 
}

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention which machine you are building for, but I suspect it has bluetooth enabled in the MACHINE_FEATURES. I also didn't look at the bb file for core-image-minimal closely, so could be something else.

Comment: I looked into it but MACHINE_FEATURES  is not changed anywhere ( in minimal recipe or local confg files)

Comment: Check in the machine recipe itself, or call "bitbake core-image-minimal -e" check its output and you will be able to see where and how MACHINE_FEATURES get its value